# Python Beginner question - Or function not working when writing a basic if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
age = float(input('enter age '))

if age != 10 or age != '11':
    print('you are not 10 or 11. ')
else:
    print('you are 10 or 11')
```

When i run this code it always prints ('you are not 10 or 11') regardless of age ?

Comment: `age` cannot be both 10 and 11 at the same time. It will be *not 10* **or** *not 11*. If it's 10, then it's not 11 and vice versa.

Comment: Please tell me, when will the condition be false?

Comment: Also note that `'11'` is a string…

Comment: float(11)  is not the same as '11'

Comment: Your test `age != 10 or age != '11'` is always going to be `True`, since it can't be both `10` and `'11'` at the same time.  Change the `or` to `and`.  Also, change `'11'` to `11`.  What you have now is a string, which will not compare equal to any number.

Comment: thanks guys, also sorry about the 11 being in a string that was a dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things not working here:

```
age = float(input('enter age '))
```

If age is an integer, you should keep is an integer and not convert it to a float. Since you're a beginner, I won't go into detail, just mention that this can lead to unexpected problems. If you want to know more, read this:
[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

You can fix this by doing this, which will convert your input age into an integer:

```
age = int(input('enter age '))
```

Secondly, there are two problems here:

```
if age != 10 or age != '11':
```

First, the first statement `age != 10` compares age to an integer, the second statement `age != '11'` compares age to a string. Keep this consistent with the type of `age`.

Secondly, at least on of these statements will always evaluate as `True`. If age is smaller than 10 or greater than 11, both statements will be True. If age is 10, the first statement will be `False` but the second will be `True`, if age is 11 it will be the other way around. If you change `or` to `and`, this condition will only be satisfied, if age is neither 10 nor 11.

You can also do it the other way around, where you check whether your second condition is True first, which is easier to read:

```
if age == 10 or age == 11:
    print('you are 10 or 11')
else:
    print('you are not 10 or 11. ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you write that you are 10 years old, the if statement will make the following comparisons:

```
age != 10 # This returns False
```

And

```
age != '11' # This returns True
```

So when we write  `age != 10 or age != '11'` the following condition is run:

```
False or True
```

The `or` operator just needs one condition to be true to return true, so `False or True` will return `True` and enter the if statement.

As a side note, you should replace `'11'` with `11` since you want to compare with a number, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

`age = float(input('enter age '))

if (age == 10 ) or (age == 11):
print('you are 10 or 11. ')
else:
print('you are not 10 or 11') `